# Audience targeting only works when browsing from the SharePoint server, using internal address

Tags: 2007, web-part, alternate-access-mapping, audience-targeting, web-application-zones

I have a web part which I am trying to target to a specific audience (the 'Staff' audience.)

I have the web part in the home page of a site that has anonymous access enabled.

I have set the Target Audience of the webpart to 'Staff'.  The idea is that anonymous viewers can't see the web part, but logged-in members of staff *can* see the webpart.

This works fine, as long as I am browsing the site from the server on which SharePoint is running, using the internal domain name (e.g. http://localhost:5050/site).  If I view the site home page while not logged in, I can't see the webpart -- this is the correct behaviour.

However, if I view the site via the public address (e.g. http://www.realaddress.co.uk:5050/site) while not logged in, I can see the webpart.  (I shouldn't be able to -- it's only targeted at the 'Staff' audience'.)  This happens if I'm browsing either on the SharePoint server or a remote machine.

I'm a bit baffled!

Answer (score 2):

Are the external zone just an alternate access mapping (AAM) or is it an extended web app (new zone) with other authentification?

Comment: I hadn't heard of alternate access mapping before, so hadn't even set one up -- if I look at the mapping, my internal URL is the same as the public URL for the zone -- i.e. Internal URL = http://internal:5050 and Public URL = http://internal:5050 .  Obviously that doesn't look right so you've probably hit the problem, thanks!  I'm not able to test changing the URLs just yet, but will give it a try later.  Thanks for the tip.